# Python requests - Session not capturing response cookies

Tags: python, session, cookies, python-requests

I'm not sure how else to describe this. I'm trying to log into a website using the requests library with Python but it doesn't seem to be capturing all cookies from when I login and subsequent requests to the site go back to the login page.

The code I'm using is as follows: (with redactions)

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.post('https://www.website.co.uk/login', data={
        'amember_login': 'username',
        'amember_password': 'password'
    })
```

Looking at the developer tools in Chrome. I see the following:
[image]

After checking `r.cookies` it seems only that PHPSESSID was captured there's no sign of the amember_nr cookie.

The value in PyCharm only shows:

`{RequestsCookieJar: 1}<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie PHPSESSID=kjlb0a33jm65o1sjh25ahb23j4 for .website.co.uk/>]>`

Why does this code fail to save 'amember_nr' and is there any way to retrieve it?

**SOLUTION**:

It appears the only way I can get this code to work properly is using Selenium, selecting the elements on the page and automating the typing/clicking. The following code produces the desired result.

```
from seleniumrequests import Chrome

driver = Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.website.co.uk')
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='amember_login']")
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='amember_pass']")

username.send_keys("username")
password.send_keys("password")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']").click() # Page is logged in and all relevant cookies saved.
```

Comment: Set by JavaScript perhaps?

Comment: Is there any way to retrieve that? I've done a bit more digging and this seems to be some kind of bug with the requests library where cookies get lost on a redirect?

Comment: Requests doesn't execute JavaScript you can use requests-html https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/ or Selenium both should execute JavaScript, can you share the URL?

Comment: Can't share the Url unfortunately, I'd get chewed out :/ I thought Selenium would be recommended, so I'm giving that a try now, will update question if it works.

Comment: Just tried the same thing in Selenium using selenium-requests, I don't get any cookies this time.

Comment: Can you try with plain Selenium and use `print(driver.get_cookie("amember_nr"))`?

Comment: Try to first send a simple get request to the page for getting the `amember_nr` cookie and then do a subsequent post request.

Comment: Managed to figure a solution out. Turns out I have to physically automate everything through selenium. Will update OP with solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.get('https://www.website.co.uk/login')
    r = s.post('https://www.website.co.uk/login', data={
        'amember_login': 'username',
        'amember_password': 'password'
    })
```

The get request will set the required cookies.

Comment: This definitely does something... :-) I'm getting way more information than what I tried before. I'll try this and if I can get the same result, I'll mark this as an answer.

Comment: The first request will set the response headers and will be sent in further requests to the server. Happy to help :)

Comment: Yeah I've tested it with subsequent requests and I get all the data I need it ready to run through lxml. Once again, thanks. Your solution is less of a pain than Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I would use something like BurpSuite to capture ALL the data being sent to the server and sort out what headers etc are required ... sometimes people/servers to referrer checking, set cookies via JAVA or wonky scripting, even seen java obfuscation and blocking of agent tags not in whitelist etc... it's likely something the headers that the server is missing to give you the cookie.

Also you can have Python use burp as a proxy so you can see exactly what gets sent to the server and the response.

https://github.com/freeload101/Python/blob/master/CS_HIDE/CS_HIDE.py (proxy support )